# python tag span selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, selenium, parsing

- I want to use the span tag to access the class, and not through
  xpatch, well, when I try to get an empty array or an error, in this
  site I parsed the prices and when they change, they come to the
  telegram bot only prices and names
  there is an infinite loop after the start button, it will endlessly check the list in which there is already data
  it will check and if the price changes it will send a response in   telegram

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oXloI.png

```
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-
    
        import telebot 
        import re
        from selenium import webdriver
        from time import sleep
        PATH ="Desktop\parser\chromedriver"
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
        bot = telebot.TeleBot("bot api")
        
        @bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
        
        
        def start(message):  
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Create a price list")
        
            # eldorado
           
            link_eldo = "https://www.eldorado.ru/c/smartfony/b/APPLE/?page=1" 
            driver.get(link_eldo)
            
            def func (i):
                i = i + 1
                return i
            
            name_eldo_product = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div[8]/div[2]/div[1]/ul/li['func(0)']/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/a")
            price_eldo_product = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div[8]/div[2]/div[1]/ul/li['func(0)']/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/span")
```

Answer (score 0):

Forget these kind of paths: `"/html/body/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div[8]/div[2]/div[1]/ul/li['func(0)']/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/span"`, navigate by element attributes.

I'd do something like this:

```py
my_data = {}
for item in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@data-dy="product"]'):
   name_elem = item.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[@data-dy="title"]') 
   price = item.find_element_by_xpath('.//span[@data-pc="offer_price"]')
   my_data[name_elem.text] =  price.text
```